# get string value from anchor tag, when another anchor tag is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `<ul>` that is getting `<li>`s dynamically added to it while also storing a string in an array. When I click my "delete" image, I need to remove the `<li>` and the string in the array.

This is how I'm adding strings to my  `<ul>` and my array:

```
function addTab() {
        tabs.append('<li class="navHighlight">' + '<a href="#">' + title + '</a>' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="images/delete.png" class="deleteImage"/>' + '</a>' + '</li>');
    };

var found = jQuery.inArray(title, titles);
    if (found >= 0) {       

    } else {        
        titles.push(title);
        addTab();
    }
```

This is how I'm attempting to remove them:

```
$("body").on("click", ".deleteImage", function(e) {
    removeItem = $(this).closest('li a').text();
    console.log(removeItem);
    titles = jQuery.grep(titles, function(value) {
      return value != removeItem;
    });
    removeTab();
});    

function removeTab() {
    $(this).closest('.macTypeNav li').remove();
}
```

I can add both `<li>` and string values just fine, but when I try to remove them, nothing happens. The event fires from the click listener; however, the `removeItem` variable is not being set and the `<li>` is not being removed.

I would like to avoid giving each `<a>` an id as they're added, but I'm not opposed to somehow adding a class that will allow me to reference them.

Any ideas are welcome, and I'm sure this is probably fairly simple but I'm about to call it quits for the day and I can't for the life of me wrap my head around this right now.

Comment: `removeTab.call(this)`

Comment: @PSL thank you, the real trouble is the String value from the other `<a>` tag. Any ideas?

Comment: cos you are using closest wrongly. See the answer you got...

Comment: @PSL indeed, and it works. Thanks for both of your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the DOM; it is magical. Also real arguments, because global variables are not the appropriate way to pass arguments.

```
var titles = [];

function addTab(title) {
    var newTab = $("<li>", { "class": "navHighlight" });

    newTab.append($("<a>", { href: "#", text: title }));
    newTab.append($("<img>", { src: "images/delete.png", "class": "deleteImage" }));
    newTab.data("title", title);

    newTab.appendTo(tabs);
    titles.push(newTab[0]);
}

$("body").on("click", ".deleteImage", function(e) {
    var remove = $(this).closest("li");

    titles.splice(titles.indexOf(remove[0]), 1);
    remove.remove();
});
```

Comment: +1 I think I would prefer `$.inArray()` over `Array.indexOf()` because of IE :(

Comment: off topic, but your skills are very impressive for someone so young. Keep up the good work, you have a very bright future (as I'm sure you already know).

Comment: @minitech var newTab = $("<li>", { "class": "navHighlight" }); is something I found interesting. This way of defining is new to me and I liked it. +1.

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside teh `removeTab` does not refer to the `delete` element

```
$("body").on("click", ".deleteImage", function (e) {
    var removeItem = $(this).closest('li').find('a').text();
    console.log(removeItem);
    titles = jQuery.grep(titles, function (value) {
        return value != removeItem;
    });
    removeTab(this);
});

function removeTab(del) {
    $(del).closest('li').remove();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FAq3G/)

or use [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to pass a custom execution context to `removeTab` method

```
$("body").on("click", ".deleteImage", function (e) {
    removeItem = $(this).closest('li').find('a').text();
    console.log(removeItem);
    titles = jQuery.grep(titles, function (value) {
        return value != removeItem;
    });
    console.log(titles)
    removeTab.call(this);
});

function removeTab() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fv89M/)

Comment: Yet again you help me. Thank you very much sir. This works beautifully

Comment: @i_me_mine also there were few selector related issued which also is fixed